# Combining new ArangoSearch views and graph traversals

Tags: arangodb

I've read through the ArangoDB 3.4 docs and the ArangoSearch view tutorial, but I'm still unclear on if/how views can be combined with graph traversals. There is an example of a graph/view join in the tutorial; however, what I need to do is to simply filter the candidate pool resulting from a traversal with a view-based text search. For example:

"for i in 2..2 outbound start_doc edges1, inbound edges2 [filter by view] return i"

The initial 2-hop traversal from the "start_doc" vertex will result in a much smaller candidate pool than the entire collection. I want to then perform a text search on this candidate pool using a configured view (probably "text_en" analyzer).

Would i just define the view expression after the traversal? Or would I need to use a "union_distinct" function to combine the traversal and the search results? (This seem like it would be very inefficient given a potentially very large result set from the view.)

Thanks!

Comment: You could try something like: let pools =( for I In 2..2 outbound startDoc edges1, inbound edges2 return I) for pool in pools for v in view filter pool.something = v.something and [additional filters] return v

Comment: @camba1 - Yes, that's the general join pattern; however, after some testing I found this to be very slow. The view filtering is executed for each result in the "pools" result. I have tested using an intersection (not "union" as said initially) and it is far more performant: "for doc in intersection(([graph traversal]),([search expression])) return doc"  This seems to be roughly the sum of the cost of the two queries. I'm just not sure if this the best way when the search expression could return very large result sets (with a large collection and a low-selectivity query).

Comment: It should be more efficient to search for the text in the view, then start the traversal from the matches (but it may not be applicable to your use case). Edge indexes can be utilized for any starting vertices, but the ArangoSearch view inverted index can only be queried in it's entirety. It can't benefit from previous filters / traversal which leave a subset of documents remaining.

Comment: @CoDEmanX - The issue in my case is that the text view result set may be very large and many (most) of those results would be invalid starting points for the subsequent traversal. I feel like there is no universally performant approach since it's a function of two operations of unknown cost (a priori). At this point I am considering indexing additional fields to de-normalize and flatten the structure of the model enough to bound size of the text view search results.

Comment: Can you filter out invalid starting points perhaps? Or do you mean by "invalid" that the search returns a lot of documents which have no connected edges at all? That shouldn't be much of a problem. If you know of another system that supports a combined index for fulltext and graphs as you desire, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved a similar problem, perhaps it will work for you too:

```
for i in 2..2 outbound start_doc edges1, inbound edges2
filter (
    for x in view
        search i._key == x._key and search_condition
        limit 1
        return x
) != []
return i
```